# Best suited distribution for the n balls in m bins problem

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Let's say we have **n** balls distributed into **m** bins, and we want to retain a belief of the number of balls each bin has. What would be the best distribution to represent that belief? How can we update our belief after observing the number of balls in one of the bins?
I thought about using a normal distribution for each bin and then if we examine a bin and we see **k** balls in there we update the distribution of all other bins by (-k). I don't know if that's an overkill and there exists a better fitted solution. Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is a mathematics problem, not really a programming one. Assuming balls are allocated to each bin with equal probability, independent of which bins the other balls are allocated to, you should use a binomial distribution with n = the number of balls whose locations are not yet known, and p = 1/k where k is the number of bins which haven't been observed. Of course, when you look at a bin and see a number of balls, the distribution of the bin you looked at collapses to a constant; the other bins should be updated by changing n and k.

Comment: @kaya3 Thank you a lot for your comment. I will test it.